# How to inject openapi specification file with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
{
                
});
```

I have explored the `AddSwaggerGen()` method of NuGet `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to use the `path` of the already generated open API specification file.

My APIs are related to file upload in .net core and I have already written the swagger specification file `swagger.yaml` and It is working fine with [editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io/). Can anyone help me? How can I inject the generated open API specification file and use it with SwaggerUI in .net core with NuGet `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`?

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/swagger.yaml", "My API V1");
});
```

I have created a static file `/swagger/swagger.yaml` in my project But Swagger UI still using the same file which is generated by internally.

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100923/generate-yaml-swagger-using-swashbuckle/45152112) and this [article](https://jobairkhan.com/2019/03/26/generating-swagger-yaml-for-asp-net-core-api/).

Comment: I see this question is 8 months old... Did you find how to do this at the end? :)

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this. One working solution is to host open-api/swagger file in "wwwroot/swagger/swagger.yaml" and use
the static file hosting middleware. You just need the SwaggerUI dependency, nothing more.

After that, this works.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/swagger.yaml", "My API V1");
});
```

Unfortunately, I encountered the issue that the .NET core doesn't host static YAML files by default. You can solve this by either [configuring FileExtensionContentTypeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider) or [enabling serve unknown content types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-standard-content-types).

Hope that this helps.